# Can Update a photo tags in existing One

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

My question is can able to add a tag from existing one (means existing phtos).Now iam able to tag a friends in fresh upload using this code

```
private const string ExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me,user_photos,publish_stream";

[HttpPost]
[FacebookAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions, LoginUrl = "/Home/LogOn?ReturnUrl=~/Home")]
public ActionResult MensagemPost(string message)
{
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
    dynamic me = fb.Get("me");

    string friendId_1 = // get the first one friend id
    string friendId_2 = // get the second one friend id

    var tags = new[] 
    { 
        new { tag_uid = friendId_1, x = 20, y = 20 },
        new { tag_uid = friendId_2, x = 40, y = 40 },
        new { tag_uid = (string)me.id, x = 60, y = 60 }
    };

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = message;
    parameters.tags = tags;
    parameters.url = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-evheT51sfeM/TlO_wZ8YDqI/AAAAAAAAA8I/fjlg0G8AgMY/s1600/The-best-top-hd-desktop-naruto-shippuden-wallpaper-naruto-shippuden-wallpapers-hd-11.jpg";

    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/photos", parameters);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { success = true });
}
```

but cannot i update the tags in existing one.

> My try IS

```
var res = FbClient.Post("/4333418373210452/tags", PostInfo);
AccessToken = Properties.Settings.Default.FBAccessToken;
FacebookClient FbClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
var PostInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var tags = new[] { new { tag_uid = "870415313026255", tag_text = "Tag updated", x = 90, y = 110 } };
PostInfo.Add("tags", tags);
var result = FbClient.Post("/4333418373210452/tags", PostInfo);
```

This code is getting error from facebook.The error says

> (GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported post request. Please read
>   the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

i try to googling but cannot get the solution till now ..anyone help me out..your comments also welcome

Jagadeesh Govindaraj

Comment: The ID you are trying to POST to, what type of object is that you are posting to because it doesn't appear to be a valid type.

Comment: @tehspark ..thanks for your Comments..I found the solution

Comment: @tehspark  ..I just change the Post To existing PHOTO ID ..ITS WORKS ...Currently I have doing Post WITH MY FRIEND ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the solution...previously i'm try to POST REQUEST Against my friend ID, But now i changed to *phtoID*..Its Worked.

```
  AccessToken = Properties.Settings.Default.FBAccessToken;
    FacebookClient FbClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
    var PostInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var tags = new[] { new { tag_uid = "870415313026255", tag_text = "Tag updated", x = 90, y = 110 } };
    PostInfo.Add("tags", tags);
    var result = FbClient.Post("/"Existing PhotoID"/tags", PostInfo);
```